# facebook php sdk 4 version, unable to fetch user albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a facebook application via php sdk 4 version.
My code is as follows:

```
try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if ($session) {
    try {
         $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
         $response = $request->execute();
         $me = $response->getGraphObject();
         $user_id = $me->getProperty('id');
         echo $user_id;
         $accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
         echo $accessToken;
         echo "<br>".$user_id;
         $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/albums');
         $response = $request->execute();
         $userAlbums = $response->getGraphObject();
         echo $userAlbums['data'][0]['id'];


    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://apps.facebook.com/lykebook/');
$auth_url = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('user_friends', 'publish_actions', 'user_photos', 'user_status', 'friends_photos','friends_status','publish_stream'));
echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$auth_url."'</script>";
}
```

But the problem is I am not getting any album data. I don't know what the problem is? The earlier request i.e: /me is working fine. I checked that by printing $user_id. But the next request for getting albums is not working i.e /me/albums. Help me in correcting this.

Comment: I used debugging by using  echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($userAlbums);
  echo "</pre>"; and find out that all data is displaying that is I am getting all json data of albums from facebook, but unable to parse with php sdk 4. how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `getGraphObjectList()` method since you are expecting more than one object. Then the result will be an array of `GraphObject` objects, [see here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php#L148-L155).

From here, you need to access these as objects and not arrays with the helper methods available (e.g. [`getProperty()`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php#L104)).

Otherwise, you can retrieve the array backing this object with [`asArray()`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php#L85-L93).

Comment: now I am getting the following error: which I have posted in new question, how to correct that:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688580/some-of-the-aliases-you-requested-do-not-exist-a-data-id

Answer (score 0):

You could use getGraphEdge, here below the code:

```
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

    try {

        $response = $fb->get('/me/albums');
        $albums = $response->getGraphEdge();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    foreach ($albums as &$value) {
          echo $value;
    }
```